# What music theory do I need to play the piano

Tags: theory, piano

Hope you had a blessed Christmas.

I am 60 and started learning the piano 5 years ago. I have a full time demanding job so have little time, but manage to practice about an hour a day. I always believed I was too old to learn but now know this isn't the case but recognise my restrictions.

Can someone advise as to what theory I would benefit from learning in addition to learning my classical pieces. I don't want to compose or give recitals. I play for my own pleasure.

Peaceful New year to you.

Comment: Difficult to point out specifics, but have a look at ABRSM grades, theory. They sort of follow the practical side of the exams, so things that crop up will align with where you are playing-wise. I guess you're in U.K.

Comment: What theory do you **need**? None. What theory would be **helpful**? Any and all of it. I’ve yet to discover a downside to learning theory.

Comment: My grandmother started playing piano by ear at the age of 85 or something. AFAIK she didn't know any music theory, and didn't ask anyone for help, she just sat down and started to play. It wasn't about reading, just playing melodies of songs she knew. What do you want to achieve? Do you want to perform pieces to an audience... to get social status? Or do you want to make sounds that make you feel good? Do you want to express yourself? Accompany songs and sing together with someone? The piano keyboard comes with a lot of theory built in - the arrangement of white and black keys.

Comment: As you learn to play, you pick up an intuitive grasp of concepts for which you'll learn theory has names. A keyboard instrument is ideal for learning and applying theory, since it is designed to play chords, melody and harmony, and makes it easy to visualize intervals, study patterns and scales, etc.

Comment: @chembluebtinternetcom - what activities do you actually want to do? e.g. do you want to play by studying scores? Sight-read? Improvise? compose? There are lots of different things you can do on the piano - different parts of theory might help more (or less) with each.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is: none.  Music theory describes the patterns in which music is created and manipulated.  If you are playing from score sheets, those patterns are relevant in how scales are built up, but the mapping from scales to fingers is practised in scale exercises and as long as they are spelt out (not containing "etc" or "go through all keys" or similar instructions), that does not concern you.

You need to look at sightreading skills, of course, like remembering how accidentals are written down and how long they last.  That is not strictly music theory, but the patterns of possible key signatures you need to recognise are limited again because of music theoretical reasons.

Things are entirely different if you are not (solely) playing from score sheets but are trying to play by ear, or by changing stuff like transposing or accompanying in a different way or filling in material from chord symbols.  In that case, the patterns that music theory describe are not something that you will eventually get a bit of a hang of just by playing but are something that you need to acquire as a separate skill.

In a way, a statement like "I don't know any music theory, I just play by ear" is a contradiction, particularly when accompaniment comes into play.  The actual skill allowing you to gloss over music theory a lot is sightreading.

Comment: Bit of a Catch 22. There are theory facts that need to be known in order to sight-read properly. And sight-reading helps learn pieces, but is only a small part of that learning.